# Apache Cordova: How to display a slide tutorial on android when the app launches for the fisrt time?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, android-layout, cordova-plugins, carousel

I truly don't know how to fix it, I was looking for the tutorial from any sites, any video, and I can't find it especially for cordova

Note: I'm using AngularJS

Answer (score 0):

Without your code, we can not help you, but here are some advice to do the job :

Cordova is based on HTML/JS/CSS, so implementing an "basic" slider ll do the job for you.
check this one, simple and working on mobile :

```
https://codepen.io/zuraizm/pen/vGDHl
```

by default hide the slider :

```
$('#slider').hide();
```

and to launch it just one time create an simple variable and save it into localStorage.

```
  localStorage.setItem('slider_viewed', 1);
```

once done, modify your slider code and check if variable is not in localstorage, you ll show the slider to the user.

```
if(localStorage.getItem('slider_viewed')==1) $('#slider').show();
```

Comment: I supposed that we create it using some plugin, that's why I'm not put some code

Comment: anyway, I'm still learning using angularjs, how to implement that code in angularjs? Help me please

Comment: follow this tutorial https://www.techiediaries.com/use-javascript-in-angular/ to insert your slider into angular